# Воспроизведение интернет - радио, в формате AAC

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Здравствуйте!
Прочитал на просторах англоязычного интернета, что для декодирования aac, нужно платить.
Нашел [какой-то декодер](https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/downloads/detail?name=aacdecoder-android-libs-0.8.zip&can=2&q=) 
, но пишут, что наже используя его нужно платить. Да и все равно описания библиотечки ненашел. Суть моей задачи: есть онлайн радиостанция, нужно чтобы приложение позволяло пользователю его слушать. Делаю впервые по теме не шарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя с [данных этой страницы](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) - андроид с версии 4.1 поддерживает AAC.  И в этом случае лицензию не нужно будет покупать. Все уже оплачено:)